# Eclipse CDT Unresolved inclusion

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I've code that already compiled using makefiles.
I'm trying to edit it using Eclipse 4.2.
My problem is with some includes that are not resolved:

```
#include <kik/sip/sip_api.h>
```

The file sip_api.h is in kik/sip/kk/include .

I've added the relevant directory to the project includes.

What is the problem?

Comment: Make sure you add the `kik` folder and not the `kik/sip/` folder.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.